# Why did Apache IoTDB reported `Execute FragmentInstance failed` when using Ratis consensus to write data?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

There was an error about Ratis consensus when writing data into Apache IoTDB. The error message is `org.apache.iotdb.rpc.StatementExecutionException: 301: [EXECUTE_STATEMENT_ERROR(301)] Exception occurred: insertRecords failed. canot fetch schema, status is: 301, msg is: Execute FragmentInstance failed: Ratis request failed ong.apache.ratis.thirdparty.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 2.999916998s`. Do I need to adjust any configuration parameters and how should I change them?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the `RPC` sent within the cluster of Apache IoTDB had timed out. You can check whether the GC time set is relatively long. The default timeout of Version 1.3.0 of Apache IoTDB is 10s and this configuration parameter is adjustable.You can upgrade your IoTDB to this version and the probability of such problem happened will be smaller.